# python xlsxwriter unique fill colors

Tags: python

I am using Python's xlsxwriter and I want to write data to cells with different fill colors.

Here is what I have tried

```py
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example_color.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

cell_format = wb.add_format()

cell_format.set_bg_color('red')
ws.write(0, 0, "red",cell_format)

cell_format.set_bg_color('green')
ws.write(0, 1, "green",cell_format)

cell_format.set_bg_color('blue')
ws.write(0, 2, "blue",cell_format)

wb.close()
```

I would expect this to work, but it always assigns the last color as the fill color for all cells. For example in the above code will result in blue fill color for all three cells and if I switch blue and green it will use green as the fill color all cells.

How can I uniquely assign colors to cells using xlsxwriter?

Comment: I've never used the library but does creating different format objects for each colour change anything?

Comment: Glad it worked out